# Monitor database activity

Tags: sql-server

I would like to see what queries are being sent to a DB and what is returned. Is this possible with MsSQL Server Management Studio or a third party application?
 Is there anything i can use that is free?

Comment: What, exactly, are you after? There are many ways ranging from trace to server level audits. Picking a good solution depends on what's the scenario.

Comment: Thanks! Im looking to see the SQL queries that are sent.

Comment: What for, idle curiosity? Usually there's a reason _why_ one would like to see the queries. Maybe that would be good solution, maybe not as per [the XY problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: Im learning a new system of applications and thought it would help me to see how it interacts with the DB

Comment: I would say [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/66261/9031) can be helpful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find a long running query with process ID, process name , login time, user , start time and duration?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66249/how-do-i-find-a-long-running-query-with-process-id-process-name-login-time-u)

Answer (score 1):

You can as a minimum execute `sp_who2` that will show session information, but more advanced and detailed methods are available, plenty of scripts available, it depends what you are after specifically.

Great set of tools available at Brent Ozar: [First Responder Kit](https://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/)

If you want a better tool to just look at  queries that are currently running, try [sp_WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com), by Adam Machanic.